# Warnings thrown when accessing methods of reference class through RStudio

Tags: r, reference-class

The code and the warnings:

```
tinyclass <- setRefClass("TinyClass", methods = list(doNothing=function(){}))
tc <- tinyclass()
tc$doNothing()
NULL
Warning messages:
1: In installClassMethod(value, self, field, selfEnv, thisClass) :
  method .objectPackage from class TinyClass was not processed into a class method until being installed.  Possible corruption of the methods in the class.
2: In installClassMethod(value, self, field, selfEnv, thisClass) :
  method .objectParent from class TinyClass was not processed into a class method until being installed.  Possible corruption of the methods in the class.
```

I also get this from the code supplied in the help page for `setRefClass`, and on any other class I try to make. I get it reliably on a Mac running R 3.2.2 which I installed myself, and intermittently on several real and virtual Windows 64 machines running R 3.2.1 which were installed by an IT department.

I am using RStudio 0.99.467.  I have the following packages installed:
datasets, graphics, grDevices, methods, stats, utils.

NEW INFO:

It seems that the problem occurs when I run the code through RStudio, but not through the native R gui.

Loaded packages in RStudio:

> search()
>    [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "tools:rstudio"     "package:stats"     "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices" "package:utils"
>    [7] "package:datasets"  "package:methods"   "Autoloads"         "package:base"

Loaded packages in native R:

> search()
>    [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "tools:RGUI"        "package:stats"     "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices" "package:utils"
>    [7] "package:datasets"  "package:methods"   "Autoloads"         "package:base"

Thoughts?
Thanks

Comment: Please add the non-base packages you use.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the format.  I've added the installed packages as they appear in the Packages tab in RStudio, but they all look like base ones to me.

Comment: Yes, you are right, they are. Strangely, I got an error first. However, now, I got neither error not warning while running your sample code.

Comment: Yes, I think I saw an error flash past the first time I used setRefClass, but I assumed, being new to R, that it was my fault.  Not sure now.

Comment: So, what did you do to fix this? I have the same issue.

Comment: @rafstraumur I found that it was just RStudio entering a bad state.  If I terminated R (not just a restart), the error went away; but I still don't really understand why it occurred to begin with.

Comment: Well, than it is obviously a bug and should be reported. This is an annoying waste of time. I wish the R community was bigger,

Comment: Encountered exactly the same problem today. Wasted lots of time in debugging. I thought it was my fault.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a problem anymore.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this bug seems to be fixed.